# How to improve performance of a Python script using Pandas and the SciKitLearn Stack?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I've created a script to match climate data between Brazilian cities using Python and the SciKitLearn stack. At the moment, I'm using MongoDB with climate collections with 60M+ entries, and Pandas to query and join over these tables.

I compare climate data from every Brazilian city with each other with a simple algorithm to generate a final score for each pair of cities.

The problem is that it takes too long (11 seconds per pair). This is really slow, since I want to get the score for all the 12M+ possible combinations. How can I make it faster? Here is the relevant code:

Connecting with MongoDB (almost instant):

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.agricredit_datafetcher_development
```

Fetching climate data (fast, but not instant):

```
base_weather_data = list(db.meteo_data_weather_data.find({'weather_station_id': ObjectId(base_weather_station['_id'])}))
target_weather_data = list(db.meteo_data_weather_data.find({'weather_station_id': ObjectId(target_weather_station['_id'])}))


return {'base_dataframe': pd.DataFrame(base_weather_data),
       'target_dataframe': pd.DataFrame(target_weather_data)}
```

Getting data from embedded (nested) Mongo collections (slow):

```
base_dataframe = dataframes['base_dataframe'].set_index('analysis_date')['weather_forecast'].apply(pd.Series)
target_dataframe = dataframes['target_dataframe'].set_index('analysis_date')['weather_forecast'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Querying to remove empty values and joining the DataFrames (fast, but not instant):

```
available_forecast_data = base_dataframe[base_dataframe['weather_forecast'] > 0][['weather_forecast']]
to_be_compared_data = target_dataframe[target_dataframe['weather_forecast'] > 0][['weather_forecast']]

join_dataframe = available_forecast_data.join(to_be_compared_data, how='inner', lsuffix='_base', rsuffix='_target')
```

Then I apply the scoring algorithm (which is pretty fast, just sums and averages) and then insert it into my Mongo database.

How can I improve my code?

Here are some points:

- I'm pretty sure if that I'm able handle embedded MongoDB data (third step) without using creating a new DataFrame the `pd.Series` method. I've already tried `json.normalize` my Mongo collection and then transforming it to a Dataframe, but it's slow as well and some data get screwed when I do this.
- The bottleneck is on the described steps. All the other steps (scoring algorithm, for instance) are instant;
- I'm relying on Pandas to do the querying, groupings and creating Dataframes. Is that OK? I'm tempted to try Mongo Aggregation Framework to see if I got any improvements. Is it worth it?
- Is Hadoop/Spark a way to improve this? I'm having a hard time to understand their role on a Data Science project;

**EDIT: Third point solved! Used Mongo Aggregations instead of applying `pd.Series` method to the dataframe:**

```
pipeline = [
    {"$match" : {"weather_station_id": ObjectId(weather_station_id)}},
    {"$project": {
      'analysis_date': "$analysis_date",
      'rainfall': "$rainfall.rainfall",
      'agricultural_drought': "$rainfall.agricultural_drought",
      'weather_forecast': "$weather_forecast.med_temp"
      }
    }
]
```

Now it takes ~1.2s for each pair of cities. But I feel I still can improve this... now the bottleneck is on the `weather_data` querying. It is indexed, though, is there any way to make it faster?

**EDIT 2: Parallelizing my task with `JobLib` (https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) scaled my script virtual speed by 3-4 times :)**:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(insert_or_read_scores_on_db)(city['name']) for city in cities)
```

Still looking for improvements, though

Comment: Btw, `meteo_data_weather_data`, which is the 60M+ entry database is indexed by `weather_station_id `, so I don't think there is a way to improve performance on the second step.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions which might be helpful to you.

1) In 2nd step you are using dataframe apply function which applies on each cell of column. If somehow you can write a for loop to do that than you can use python Numba library which is famous for doing things in parallel. You can create a function with for loop and in that function you can give decorator @jit which does parallel work in multicore CPU. You need to do from numba import jit

2) I have seen one video of professor of university of washington while doing course on coursera where he teaches how to use map reduce algorithm to do JOIN of two tables which can be run in parallel. That way you can do Join also fast if it runs in parallel.

Comment: Your first statement helped me improve the third point. I didn't know that the `apply` function worked on each cell at once. I resolved that by using MongoDB aggregations instead. TY, and see my edit above!